# JAVA Scan from textfile and display only text between two key words/variables

Tags: java

I need help displaying only text from within a file that begins with lets say the word "Hello" and ends at the word "Bye". I'm able to scan the whole text file and print it, but I need it to only print out a specific range defined by two variables. This is what I have so far, any tips will be appreciated. Thanks! :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    File fileName = new File("hello.txt");
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileName);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a state variable to store whether you are between a "Hello" / "Bye" pair or not. Change the variable according to what you find in the input. Print lines according to the state you are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How big is the file? I unless its large, read the file as a string and cut out the bit you want.

```
File file = new File("Hello.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
fis.read(bytes);
fis.close();
String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf("START"), text.lastIndexOf("END")));
```

Using Apache FileUtils

```
String text = FileUtils.readFileToString("hello.txt");
System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf("START"), text.lastIndexOf("END")));
```

Comment: Using the fis work, thanks! Now looking into how to have it only displayed once, because they're multiple "Bye" throughout the text file and it's containing all ofthem. But progress indeed, thanks again!

Comment: Do you want to start at the first Bye (using indexOf), or the last?  You have decide.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    File fileName = new File("hello.txt");
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileName);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            int indexHello = line.lastIndexOf("hello",0);
            int indexBye = line.indexOf("bye". indexHello);
            String newString = line.substring(indexHello, indexBye);


        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you meant that Hello and Bye had to be on the same line or spanned over multiple lines? Try this (modify startToken and endToken to suit):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    File fileName = new File("hello.txt");
    try {
        String startToken = "Hello";
        String endToken = "Bye";
        boolean output = false;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileName);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            if (!output && line.indexOf(startToken) > -1) {
                output = true;
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf(startToken)+startToken.length());
            } else if (output && line.indexOf(endToken) > -1) {
                output = false;
                System.out.println(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(endToken)));
            }

            if (output) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state variable to store whether you are between a "Hello" / "Bye" pair or not. Change the variable according to what you find in the input. Print text according to the state you are in.

I leave the implementation in Java to you. :-)